# Call controller function from typeahead dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering how to call a controller function on selecting an option from the dropdown generated by bootstrap typeahead. Every item on dropdown has a unique id. I need to pass it to the other function when selecting the option.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="stock" ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
    <h2>Stock Search</h2>
      <input type="text" ng-model="val" placeholder="Search for a stock" uib-typeahead="obj as obj.name for obj in result | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10" ng-keydown="main.getStock(val)" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control" my-enter="main.getDetails(result)">
    <div ng-show="noResults">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
angular.module('stock', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}])

.directive('myEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.myEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
})

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http){

    var app = this;
    app.config = {
      headers: {
        'User-ID': 379,
        'Access-Token':'eWEyOS5HbHNwQkRCVUJPX2d0UUNGUVR4Z1NKRTgzUkdCWHB2V1NCbWwtckNHWW5iS05NSjJLY0J5YU5CeU5QWFhTU3R5N1phdTctd250aW15dk5ZUFcySEt3ckpxNUdCNFhwQzYyNGVQcnlKSWlYa21Fa0xvQ0hIZ1kxZVRjaU0wJVVTRVIlMzc5',
        'User-IP':'0.0.0.0',
        'Agent':'agent'
        }
      };

   $scope.result = [];
   this.getStock = function(val){
   $http.get("https://staging.investo2o.com/assetmanager-ws/api/v1/assets/getassets?query="+val+"&assetType=STK", app.config)
                 .then(function(response){
                    $scope.result = response.data;
                    return $scope.result;
             });
      }

   this.getDetails = function(id){
      console.log(id);
   }               

})//end of ctrl
```

How do I do this?

Comment: use angular-ui-bootstrap typeahead and follow docs and examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask for attrs.myEnter, that is just a string that contains your expression. scope.$eval takes that string and evaluates it against the scope. But I think that $eval isn't intended for taking a string that contains a function and actually executing that function. It is more about being able to report on values that exist on the scope with a shorter syntax. If you want to go that route, look at the $parse service.

However, the way you're probably "supposed" to do it is to add a scope property to your directive definition object, you can set myEnter to "&", which will then give you a function in `scope.myEnter`. When you run that function, it will be like running the code in the my-enter attribute.